# how to start hiding from 100px from top after used affix bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to start  hiding content 100px from top. I have applied Bootstrap Affix with Nav in same div. but when i am scrolling up affix work fine but i want to hide div after affix div not from browser top.
Here is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-9">                
<div class="header-affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50" data-offset-bottom="380" style="z-index: 1" id="header">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <ul class="nav nav-inline act-details" id="menu" role="navigation">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#desc">Description</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#img">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#maps">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#details">Details</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="act-detail">
    <div class="description" id="desc"></div>
    <div class="images" id="img"></div>
    <div class="maps" id="maps"></div>
    <div class="details" id="details"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file

```
 .affix {
        top: 100px
    }
```

Comment: I want act-detail should start hiding post affix 100px as right now i am getting nav class change after its reaches to top 0 px